# Why is the default storage-level of persist different between docs and code's comments?

Tags: apache-spark

The Spark document says that the default storage-level is MEMORY_ONLY, however, the source code comments says it is MEMORY_AND_DIST.

```scala
/**
 * Persist this Dataset with the default storage level (`MEMORY_AND_DISK`).
 *
 * @group basic
 * @since 1.6.0
 */
def persist(): this.type = {
  sparkSession.sharedState.cacheManager.cacheQuery(this)
  this
}
```

Comment: probably a bug with the doc/code , if you want you can create a PR for the spark community and Im sure they'll approve it. code and docs are never perfect and spark is no different. give a hand and help.

Comment: can you share the link to the documentation, My be you are referring to dataset and sql in the code and RDD in the documentation

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I checked the doc of RDD, but saw the source code of Dataset. So, I went to see the source code of RDD. Yes, they are consistent. Link of Dataset.scala: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala Link of RDD.scala: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala.

Comment: @llya Thank your reply. It is my fault. I should see the source code of RDD.scala. I saw the Dataset.scala.